# Multiple celerycam procceses on the same server

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have two celerycam processes configured for running under supervisor. Here is part of my supervisord.conf:

```
[program:dev1_celerycam]    
directory = /var/www/dev1.example.com
command = /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/dev1.example.com/manage.py celerycam --logfile=/var/log/supervisor/dev1_celerycam.log --workdir=/var/www/dev1.example.com
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/dev1_celerycam_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/dev1_celerycam.log
exitcodes=0,2
priority=993

[program:dev_celerycam]    
directory = /var/www/dev.example.com
command = /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/dev.example.com/manage.py celerycam --logfile=/var/log/supervisor/dev_celerycam.log --workdir=/var/www/dev.example.com
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/dev_celerycam_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/dev_celerycam.log
exitcodes=0,2
priority=995
```

Also I have two processes of celeryd in the supervisord.conf. They starts perfectly fine on the same server. But for one of celerycam processes I get next in supervisord.log:

```
2013-09-01 09:35:12,546 INFO exited: dev_celerycam (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-09-01 09:35:12,546 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-09-01 09:35:15,555 INFO spawned: 'dev_celerycam' with pid 25504
2013-09-01 09:35:16,540 INFO exited: dev_celerycam (exit status 1; not expected)
2013-09-01 09:35:16,540 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2013-09-01 09:35:17,542 INFO gave up: dev_celerycam entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

This occurs for  dev_celerycam or dev1_celerycam on supervisord restart. One of them starts fine while another one fails. Looks like it happens randomly.

Is there any chance to get both celerycam processes working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both celerycam process created pid file in the same path somehow. Had to add --pidfile parameter for each of celerycam processes.